# Setting up a preferred network interface in linux

Tags: networking, ssh, interface

I need to set up the network interfaces of a linux box running Ubuntu Server. The box will be deployed in an industrial vehicle and will operate headless (i.e. no monitor, no keyboard/mouse).

The software running on the box requires internet access, so it will be connected to a mobile router that is mounted on the vehicle as well; this connection may be via eth0 (cable) or wlan0 (wireless). I set up these interfaces in the /etc/network/interfaces file.

Now the problem I haven't solved yet: the linux box will be physically inaccessible (so no chance of plugging in a cable after deployment), but it will be necessary for a technician with a windows laptop to connect wirelessly to the linux box and to ssh into it. That means, the linux box needs to be set up such that if the technician's laptop is in the proximity, then it will connect automatically to the laptop's ad-hoc network and accept ssh connections over that interface. The internet connection via the other interfaces don't need to remain available during that time (or may not be available at all, as some vehicles may have no router). If the technician goes away, then the linux box should automatically shut down the interface over which it connected to the windows laptop and resume normal operation.

I have been googling various bits for days, but so far I have no idea how to solve this problem. I thought maybe I could define two wireless interfaces in the /etc/network/interfaces file, one assigned to the router on the vehicle, and one assigned to the technician's laptop; then, define the latter as "preferred network" and have the linux box automatically go for the preferred network whenever it becomes available. Is that possible? If yes, how?

I will be very grateful for any hint. However, please post only solutions NOT USING graphical tools, as the linux box runs no X server.

Comment: Is it not an option for you to ssh to your device over the internet?

Comment: No.  The vehicle may not have internet a router.